# How to create a .csv table from an output result in R?

Tags: r, csv

I am running Flexmix code and it returns the value of BIC and AIC like this.

```
    set.seed(1)

    mp8<-initFlexmix(. ~ .|id, data=op18, k=8, model=list(Model_tc1,Model_1), nrep=100)

    BIC(mp2,mp3,mp4,mp5,mp6,mp7,mp8)
    AIC(mp2,mp3,mp4,mp5,mp6,mp7,mp8)


    result
    > BIC(mp2,mp3,mp4,mp5,mp6,mp7,mp8)
             df      BIC
     mp2  50.03105 84912.01
     mp3  78.11906 78081.28
     mp4 108.32396 74303.05
     mp5 137.38793 72677.82
     mp6 165.54544 71368.86
     mp7 190.11087 69935.62
     mp8 194.56414 70693.15
    > AIC(mp2,mp3,mp4,mp5,mp6,mp7,mp8)
             df      AIC
     mp2  50.03105 84496.94
     mp3  78.11906 77433.18
     mp4 108.32396 73404.36
     mp5 137.38793 71538.02
     mp6 165.54544 69995.46
     mp7 190.11087 68358.42
     mp8 194.56414 69079.00
```

I would like to turn the result into an excel or csv file to use later. What possibilities do I have?

Comment: Look into using `write.csv`.

Comment: the sink function can be useful https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to save it in a csv you can either use `write.csv` or `write.table`:
`write.table` is a little more flexible.
It could look like this

```
write.table(mydata, file = "mycsv.csv", sep = ",", dec = ".", row.names = F)
```

See `?write.table` for more info.

To save it into an xlsx you can use the `openxlsx` package:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(mydata, file = "myxlsx.xlsx")
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset is big, you may want to consider converting your table to a `data.table` and then writing it to a .csv with `fwrite`.

From `?fwrite`:

> As ‘write.csv’ but much faster (e.g. 2 seconds versus 1 minute) and just as flexible. Modern machines almost surely have more than one CPU so ‘fwrite’ uses them; on all operating systems including Linux, Mac and Windows.

`data.table` is a package that allows you to process, explore and manage your data. Again, from `?data.table`:

> ‘data.table’ *inherits* from ‘data.frame’. It offers fast and memory efficient: file reader and writer, aggregations, updates,
>   equi, non-equi, rolling, range and interval joins, in a short and flexible syntax, for faster development.
>
> It is inspired by ‘A[B]’ syntax in R where ‘A’ is a matrix and ‘B’ is a 2-column matrix. Since a ‘data.table’ *is* a ‘data.frame’, it is compatible with R functions and packages that accept *only*
>   ‘data.frame’s.

You may want to check into its `vignette(package = "data.table")`